# Like and dislike button with local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I have my like and dislike buttons which you can toggle but I would like to know how to use local storage to make it have the same position when I refresh the page

If anyone can help me with this

Thanks

the code is attached below

```js
var btn1 = document.querySelector('#green');
var btn2 = document.querySelector('#red');

btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
    if (btn2.classList.contains('red')) {
      btn2.classList.remove('red');
    } 
  this.classList.toggle('green');
  
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
    if (btn1.classList.contains('green')) {
      btn1.classList.remove('green');
    } 
  this.classList.toggle('red');
  
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 40px;
}

button{
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  color: #AAA;

}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.green{
  color: green;
}

.red{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/fe459689b4.js"></script>

  <button class="btn" id="green"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  <button class="btn" id="red"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Comment: local storage means after refreshing your page the entire code renderd itself . so any changes will not be saved in your cookies . so you can implement backend models to store your data such as in localstorage or cloud based !!

Comment: Don't use two classes. Logic. You need only one class: `.is-disliked`

Comment: Also, don't use IDs for atoms (buttons, etc) use classes. IDs must be unique on a page, you're limiting yourself to a code that will only work for two elements.

Comment: Also `.btn:focus {outline: none;}` is really bad for a11y (accessibility).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```js
const btn1 = document.querySelector('#green');
const btn2 = document.querySelector('#red');

const likeStatus = localStorage.getItem('like-status');
if (likeStatus) {
  if (likeStatus === 'liked') {
    btn1.classList.add('green');
  }
  if (likeStatus === 'disliked') {
    btn2.classList.add('red');
  }
}

btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setButtonColorAndAddToLocalStorage(btn1, 'green', btn2, 'red', 'liked');
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setButtonColorAndAddToLocalStorage(btn2, 'red', btn1, 'green', 'disliked');
});

setButtonColorAndAddToLocalStorage = (elm, elmClass, altElm, altElmClass, status) => {
  const elmStatusSet = elm.classList.contains(elmClass);
  elm.classList.toggle(elmClass);
  altElm.classList.remove(altElmClass);
  localStorage.setItem('like-status', elmStatusSet ? '' : status);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### Saving info into Local Storage

For saving info into Local Storage you must call the method `window.localStorage.setItem([KEY], [VALUE])`.
Take in mind that you can only save ***String*** type into local storage, so if you want to save an *Array*, of an *Object* you must call `JSON.stringify([YOURDATA])` before saving it into Local Storage.

### Load info from Local Storage

For loading info into Local Storage you must call the method `window.localStorage.getItem([KEY])`.
As I already mention before this data saved is a **String** so if you want to take another type of data you must parse it (Ex.: `JSON.parse([YOURDATA])`, `parseInt([YOURDATA])`).

As a plus you can remove complete the key and the data with `window.localStorage.removeItem([KEY])` method.

**Note**: *[KEY]*, *[VALUE]* and *[YOURDATA]* are obviously placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by modifying your js code a little bit.
This saves the state and clicks the buttons automaticly on reload.

```
var btn1 = document.querySelector('#green');
var btn2 = document.querySelector('#red');

btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
    if (btn2.classList.contains('red')) {
      btn2.classList.remove('red');
    } 
  this.classList.toggle('green');
localStroage.setItme("like", "like");
  
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
    if (btn1.classList.contains('green')) {
      btn1.classList.remove('green');
    } 
  this.classList.toggle('red');
localStroage.setItme("like", "dislike");

  
});
window.onload = function () {
if (localStorage.getItem("like") == "like") {
document.getElementById('green').click()
}
else {
    document.getElementById('red').click()
}
```